# BroadcastReceiver fires only second time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am checking Internet Connection by pinging to google.If there is no network or response is not successful I send a broadcast with a message that there is no Internet. Whenever I click a Textview in Navigation Drawer it must check whether there is internet connection.Whenever there is no internet and I click the textview it is not checked, it is checked only second time I click the Textview.The onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver is not called the first time.

Below is the code:

```
public void checkInternetConnection()
    {
        connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        try {
            if (networkInfo!=null)
            {
                if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE || networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                {
                    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().
                            connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                            writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).
                            readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(googleurl).build();
                    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            Log.e("error", "error");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            hasInternet1 = false;
                            Intent intent=new Intent("itrnt_avl");
                            intent.putExtra("inernet_availability",false);
                            sendBroadcast(intent);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                            Log.e("Response", response.body().string());
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                hasInternet1 = true;
                                Intent intent=new Intent("itrnt_avl");
                                intent.putExtra("inernet_availability",true);
                                sendBroadcast(intent);


                            } else {
                                Log.e("Response", "No response");
                                hasInternet1 = false;
                                Intent intent=new Intent("itrnt_avl");
                                intent.putExtra("inernet_availability",false);
                                sendBroadcast(intent);
                                throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response.body().string());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    hasInternet1 = false;
                    Log.e("Response", "No network type");
                    Intent intent=new Intent("itrnt_avl");
                    intent.putExtra("inernet_availability",false);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            }
            else {
                hasInternet1=false;
                Log.e("Response", "network null");
                Intent intent=new Intent("itrnt_avl");
                intent.putExtra("inernet_availability",false);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Intent intent=new Intent("itrnt_avl");
            intent.putExtra("inernet_availability",false);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

 bad_dates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    drawerlayout.closeDrawers();
     checkInternetConnection();
     if (broadcastReceiver==null)
     {
     Log.e("Receiver","Not null");

     broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.e("OnReceive","Called");

     hasInternet1=intent.getBooleanExtra("inernet_availability",false);
     unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
     broadcastReceiver=null;
     if (hasInternet1){
     new BackgroundTask1().execute();
     }
     else {
     Log.e("Internet Status","No Internet");
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please check your 
     InternetConnection and try again later",                       
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            };
     registerReceiver(broadcasteceiver,new IntentFilter("itrnt_avl"));
                        }
      });
```

Comment: Question has been edited.Please read again..

Comment: I can see that you are first calling the method `checkInternetConnection()` and then registering for the receiver. Can you try registering first and then calling the method `checkInternetConnection()`?

Comment: ya bcoz i send broadcast in checInternetConnection() after checking if there is internet or not

Comment: Wouldn't that give me Internet unavailable since onReceive is called before Internet is checked

Comment: isn't the `broadcastReceiver` the receiver of the broadcast posted by `checkInternetConnection()`?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: No, it won't. `onReceive()` will only be executed once its receives the registered broadcast.

Comment: Will try it now

Comment: It works. Why didnt it work prevoiusly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is you are first calling the `checkInternetConnection()` which is posting the broadcast and then registering for it. Which means, first time there is no one to receive the broadcast.

When you run the `checkInternetConnection()` second time, you have already registered the receiver first time, hence it receives the broadcast.

So, you will have to register the broadcast receiver first and then call the method `checkInternetConnection()`.

Also, as asked by you in the comment, the `broadcastReceiver` is the registered received. The method `onReceive()` will only get executed when the resisted broadcast is received.